# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it in selenium python when i use try except block

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, devtools, try-except, nosuchelementexception

**I want the browser shoud't shut down when he can't find class for this i use try except block try-except is running but my browser is closing when try line come for execution but print line is executing in cmd**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import subprocess

# change as per requirement
email = "example@example.com"
password = "example"
MN = "mad max: fury road"

print("process Started")

with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\bot\chromedriver.exe") as d:
    d.maximize_window()

    d.get("https://sflix.to/search/troll") 
    # locate the search bar element and enter the keyword
    time.sleep(5)
    d.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".form-control.search-input").send_keys(MN) #entering keyword
    d.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".form-control.search-input").send_keys(Keys.RETURN) #enter
    # locate the first search result link

try:
    elem = d.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "fd-btn").click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    # add any further steps here
print("this will be print")
```

when try line come for execution my browser suddenly shut down with error message

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56105/devtools/browser/86b384ff-9334-4e10-bd7c-fb96089e9bb3
[6664:6856:0127/223501.827:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [22:35:01.827] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=56101): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/9ed569aae6e76e66149858a493add9ba/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001AE6C76F090>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))"
```

but my cmd paste this will be print

i tried nosuchelement instead of Exception as

```
try:
    elem = d.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "fd-btn").click()
    elem.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Element not found")
```

i check firewall too chrome was checked
i changed the device but it didn't work
i haven't tried changing browser because firfox gecko giving me error app can't run your pc same with edge